# How can I gain the Analytical badge?

Tags: support, badges

Is there any way of gaining the analytical badge now that it has been retired.

I have read the posts regarding combining accounts where one already had the badge, however, this would require having the badge in the first place.

I notice some people have been awarded it recently and find it hard to believe that all these people have combined accounts.

Answer (score 21):

> I notice some people have been awarded it recently and find it hard to believe that all these people have combined accounts.

Yet that is exactly what happens. People create new accounts by accident all the time. You can then correct the mistake by [requesting that the accounts be merged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts); the process isn't all that arduous.

What happens in that people have an old account, one created a few years ago. Then after a long absence they have a new question, create a new account, then discover all their points are gone, rediscover their old account and request a merge.

In the past month only 3 people were re-awarded the analytical badge, this is not exactly common.

Nothing has changed here; if you did not earn the badge in the past, you cannot earn it today.

Comment: In that case would it be possible to have my account merged with one that already has the analytical badge please :) we have a competition in the office at work to see if anyone can actually achieve it.

Comment: @DAVEWASLIN: that is entirely the wrong reason to achieve a badge. You can't, not unless you *already have an account of your own with the badge*.

Comment: @DAVEWASLIN You can't. You can't. You can't. You can't. You can't. Sorry.

Comment: @DAVEWASLIN if you really need that badge that badly, the solution is pretty obvious.... you need to invent a time machine, go back to the time when the analytical was awarded, earn it on a new account, then come back in time and merge your current account with that one.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Who cares about the analytical badge? I'm working on a time machine to get the [precognitive](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive) badge.